# Remove duplicate rows from listbox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

Creating a userform to search through information contained in an eight column worksheet and display the matching rows in a listbox. The listbox displays eight columns of data too. Through some research, I found a link with some helpful information ("http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/580692-how-delete-duplicates-listbox.html", but it's not producing the desired output. Here's the code from my workbook:

```
Sub FindPastDueCustomers
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim nodupes As New Collection
    Dim Swap1, Swap2, Item

    With frm_Customers.lbox_Customers

        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            ' The next statement ignores the error caused
            ' by attempting to add a duplicate key to the collection.
            ' The duplicate is not added - which is just what we want!
            On Error Resume Next
            nodupes.Add .List(i), CStr(.List(i))
        Next i

    '   Resume normal error handling
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Clear the listbox
        .Clear

        'Sort the collection (optional)
        For i = 1 To nodupes.Count - 1
            For j = i + 1 To nodupes.Count
                If nodupes(i) > nodupes(j) Then
                    Swap1 = nodupes(i)
                    Swap2 = nodupes(j)
                    nodupes.Add Swap1, before:=j
                    nodupes.Add Swap2, before:=i
                    nodupes.Remove i + 1
                    nodupes.Remove j + 1
                End If
            Next j
        Next i

    '   Add the sorted and non-duplicated items to the ListBox
        For Each Item In nodupes
            .AddItem Item
        Next Item

    End With
'   Show the UserForm
    frm_Customers.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: `...but it's not producing the desired output.` What does it do instead?

Comment: It produces only the first column of the matching row; the remaining seven columns from the worksheet are not shown.

Comment: You are not adding the other columns to the collection. You are only adding the first column to the collection. You then clear the listbox completely. You then add the collection items to the listbox.

Comment: Please forgive me for being a VBA newbie, but could you please show me how to add the remaining columns to the collection?

Comment: No worries. It has nothing to do with being new at VBA. How to do what you want is not something that is widely known.

Comment: Perhaps I stumped by your suggestion because I'm so new to VBA. Could you please tell me what lines of my code to tweak using your suggestions or provide more sample code to help me a long?

Answer (score 0):

Near the top, you have this line:

```
nodupes.Add .List(i), CStr(.List(i))
```

That adds only the first column of the listbox to the collection. To add eight columns instead, you need to be more specific:

```
nodupes.Add Array(.List(i, 0), .List(i, 1), .List(i, 2), .List(i, 3), .List(i, 4), .List(i, 5), .List(i, 6), .List(i, 7)), _
            .List(i, 0) & "|" & .List(i, 1) & "|" & .List(i, 2) & "|" & .List(i, 3) & "|" & .List(i, 4) & "|" & .List(i, 5) & "|" & .List(i, 6) & "|" & .List(i, 7)
```

What's the difference? Well, a collection accepts one item and one key at a time. So what the above alteration does is embeds all of the current row's (i) column values into an array and that array is added to the collection as the item. At the same time the key for that item is produced by contatenating all of the values with a pipe character.

As a simple example, imagine another scenario where the listbox had only three columns and one of the rows had these values: `a`, `b`, `c`. Adding to the collection would "literally" look like this:

```
nodupes.Add Array("a", "b", "c"), "a|b|c"
```

Hopefully that makes it easier to see what going on, when adding each row to the collection.

Comment: Wow. It's going to take me some time to wrap my head around that VBA code. Is this the only change that I need to make to solve my problem?

Comment: No. The sorting would be more involved because the values are now embedded into an array. Also, when re-filling the listbox at the end you will need to unpack the array for each row.

Comment: Thanks for your help; I will implement your solution.

Comment: I just implemented the code you provided. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me; no rows are displayed in the listbox.

Comment: Please send me the file.

Comment: Can you tell me if you tested your suggested code with a listbox having duplicate rows?

Comment: After re-examining my code, I discovered that I was missing a comma (my fault). In the course of testing it, I got a type mismatch error. I'm researching this latest error now.

Comment: I'm getting a type mismatch from the following block of code: For 'Each Item In NoDupes
            .AddItem Item
        Next Item'

Comment: Please send me the file.

Comment: "Item" is declared in the following block 'Dim Swap1, Swap2, Item'; it's missing as 'As <Type>'

Comment: Since we're adding an array to a collection, is there anything special that I must do before assigning an array to a listbox? It keeps choking at `For Each Item In NoDupes
            .AddItem Item
        Next Item`

Comment: Did you have to use a solution similar to the one described in "http://help.lockergnome.com/office/fill-MultiColumn-Listbox-additem-array--ftopict913862.html" to re-populate the listbox